# In what situations does Shannon entropy increase or decrease?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Typically when we measure information/Shannon entropy (differential entropy), it is a snapshot value at a specific point in time, so there is no talk about whether it will grow or decrease. A random variable just possesses that amount of entropy like the number of ears on a dog.

If we reconcile Shannon entropy with **time entropy**, which instead dynamically grows larger as $t\rightarrow \infty$, from the perspective that we as humans only experience time going forwards not backwards,

in what situations would we find informational disorder/transmission (information entropy) increase or decrease, given that Shannon entropy is commonly viewed as a non-dynamic snapshot value as if it were just a random variable's intrinsic property that doesn't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, entropy is a property of a random variable's distribution. So, if you want a time-variant entropy, you need to have some time-variance in your distribution, too.

One way to look at this is repeated experiments. For example, the entropy of a coin flip doesn't change over time, but you can look at the entropy of a sequence of coin-flips, which is a growing binary sequence, that changes over time. The entropy of this sequence changes over time as the sequence grows. You actually end up with very interesting phenomena in this case, a concentration of measure around what is called a typical set that contains equally likely outcomes (see asymptotic equipartition property if you're curious) and the probability of all outcomes outside this set vanishes.

Another way to have a time-variant entropy is having a distribution that evolves with time. You can define a family of random variables that is parametrized by the time index. As a simple example, let $X_t \sim \text{Uniform}(\{1/k\}_{k=1}^t)$. So, the set of values $X_t$ can take grows over time and hence entropy keeps increasing.

However, note that, the entropy doesn't always have to increase over time. You can conversely define a family, where the uncertainty decreases over time. For example, $X_t \sim \text{Uniform}([0,1/t])$ gives you $H(X_t) = \log (1/t)$.

Comment: If we let a distribution vary over time, from $k=1$ to $t$, is the number of sample observations growing?

Comment: You can look at the sequence of samples from a growing distribution as a random vector $X_1,X_2,...,X_t$. You can also get a time-varying entropy by only looking at the last sample. Basically, as long as there is a sequence of random variables, looking at the entropy of its entries gives you a sequence of entropies. You can look at that entropy sequence’s asymptotics. Depending on what you’re trying to model with $X_t$, you can add all sorts of bells and whistles to the random variable sequence.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. Are the number of observations the same or not the same

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are given a gradient flow
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=-\nabla V(x).
\end{equation}
Then, $V$ decreases along solutions since
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}V(x)=\nabla V(x)\cdot \dot{x}=-|\nabla V(x)|^{2}<0.
\end{equation}
A prototypical example of an evolution of probability measures for which you can observe a decrease of entropy is the heat flow
\begin{equation}
\partial_{t}\mu=\Delta\mu.
\end{equation}
To see why, you can either directly differantiate in $t$, $S(\mu_{t})$ with $S=\int\mu\log\mu$ or you deduce it from the fact that the heat equation can be seen as gradient flow of the entropy in Otto's Wasserstein calculus, i.e. formally
\begin{equation}
\dot\mu=-\nabla^{W}S(\mu),
\end{equation}
with $\nabla^{W}$ being the Wasserstein gradient.

Comment: what is the layman's interpretation of "gradient flow"? the temporal changes in a function's first derivative, but not taken to the extremes of its second derivative (which also represents the change in the change)?